# Extract certain offsets in a file with python

Tags: python

i am trying to learn python as i go, but i have come to a brick wall.

i am just trying to extract certain offsets in a .bin file.
i have a bin file with a length of "00FFFFF0"

lets say i want to extract from "0x3F000" with a block size of "0x800" and then put that in a file how would i go about it? i dont have any code yet and am hoping i will get some good input. i am a beginner to python (been doing it for a few months) and would like to learn how to do this really just for educational purposes.

but the point is i want to be able to extract specific (offset;block size)
i hope you understand what i mean. and i very much appreciate any help i am given. thanks

Comment: You mean like... seeking and reading?

Comment: i think so. but i need an example, could you possibly write me an example with a file name of backup.bin, and the offsets i am trying to extract are 00003F00 with a block size of 800. then save it to a file named "extracted"

Comment: In the case of Python, not only can you read documentation, but you can also use "introspection", i.e. using Python to figure out what Python can do.  If you execute `f = open("filename")` you now have the name `f` set to a file object, and if you then execute `help(f)` Python will print some terse documentation telling you what you can do with that file object.  One of the method functions documented there is the `file.seek()` function, and `file.read()` is another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [pretty self-explanatory](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), actually:

```
# Use the with statement to open a file so it will later be closed automatically
with open("in.bin", "rb") as infile:  # rb = read binary
    infile.seek(0x3F000, 0)           # 0 = start of file, optional in this case
    data = infile.read(0x800)

with open("out.bin", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(data)
```

Comment: Note that it is not necessary to use string constants and coerce them to integer using `int()`.  Python allows literals like `0x3F000` and will do the right thing with them.

Comment: you have no idea how much you just taught me man. thank you very much

Comment: with this little educational code, i will rule the world muhahahaha